# Algebraic simplifying of $\frac {a + 27}{\sqrt[3]{a} + 3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help in simplifying the expression:

$\cfrac {a + 27}{\sqrt[3]{a} + 3}$

I see that $27=3^3$ and $(\sqrt[3]{a})^3 = a$, but I do not know where to go then with it.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Here's how you can factor a sum of cubes:
$$
x^3 + y^3 = (x + y)(x^2 - xy + y^2)
$$

Comment: Oh, so easy.. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $a=u^3$ and then $a^\frac13 = u$